# How to change IntelliJ tab symbol?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3 version.

I wonder how to change tab character(symbol)?

```
func init() {
---- userDao = userDao...
}

// to

func init() {
>    userDao = userDao...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `editor.old.tab.painting=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227988).

Comment: when i enabled editor.old.tab.painting options then showing arrow character. There is no show > character?

Comment: No such option until the issue linked in my answer is fixed.